# Github 2-factor authentification in terminal with CocoaPod

Tags: git, authentication, github

After I enabled the 2-factor authentication in Github, everytime I do `pod install` or `pod update` in terminal, I have to enter username and password TWICE for the HTTPS. Why is that happening? Is there a way to bypass the password authentication part just like when I was using SSH back then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because is asking you per subSpec, the easiest way to fix this is with git credentials:

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/